# React Save multiple images to state

Tags: image, reactjs, file-upload, state

I am struggling with saving multiple images at once to my state. This is my code at the moment:

```
handleImageChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pictures = [];

        let reader = new FileReader();
        let files = e.target.files;

        var index;

        for(index = 0;index<files.length;index++){
            var file = files[index];
            var url = reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            pictures.push({'image':file, 'imagePreviewUrl':url});

            console.log(pictures);


        }

      }
```

Basically I am trying to loop through each image file, and then using an object, assign the image to the 'image'-value, and the url to the 'imagePreviewUrl'. But on each console.log, it just says indefined on the imagePreviewUrl. What am I doing wrong here? I want to make this work, and then save my pictures array in my state (appending - if existing). I am trying my best to make an image selector with preview.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you need to use the "onloadend" function included in the reader object.

this will be something like this:

```
    for(index = 0;index<files.length;index++){
        var file = files[index];
        this.handleLoadImage(file);
    }
...
...

 // class method

  handleLoadImage = (file) => {
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        // as a good practice, use a function to set state
        this.setState(() => ({
          imagePreviewUrl: reader.result,
        }));
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```